# Implementing Custom Cache Store

Tags: infinispan

Just implemented a custom cache store based on the official existing RocksDb one for a different backend store.

That leads me to a number of concerns/questions:

- Found out the hard way that PersistenceContextInitializerImpl is auto-generated and had added an import from Eclipse to resolve the issue. Now I have to leave it non-imported and showing as an error in Eclipse, is there a best practice way to handle this?
- Why is RocksDBDbStoreTest#testSegmentsRemovedAndAdded call when segmented is false, since this calls removeSegments that contractually should not be called if not segmented?
- Same class, why is buildConfig numSegments set or larger than 1 for non-segmented test cases?
- Any example of store implementing the NonBlockingStore transactional methods? Mostly wondering to make sure that all calls are from the same thread?
- Wanted to disable the compatibility test, since not supported in prior versions. Changed group to unstable or manual and would always still get called, which doesn't seem to match documentation. What is the right way to disable it from build time run?
- Are there any kind of performance/stress tests for persistence store that can be executed or adapted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Found out the hard way that PersistenceContextInitializerImpl is auto-generated and had added an import from Eclipse to resolve the issue. Now I have to leave it non-imported and showing as an error in Eclipse, is there a best practice way to handle this?

There should be a way to have it run the annotation processor. We use IntelliJ and it works fine OOTB.

> Why is RocksDBDbStoreTest#testSegmentsRemovedAndAdded call when segmented is false, since this calls removeSegments that contractually should not be called if not segmented?

This is just a side effect of having a parameterized test like that. In actual runtime it won't be invoked. You can just have the test ignore it if it is segmented.

```
if (segmented) return;
```

> Same class, why is buildConfig numSegments set or larger than 1 for non-segmented test cases?

Infinispan data container is always segmented when running any of the cluster modes. The store however is not required to be segmented in those cases. If the store is not segmented you can ignore any segment parameters as documented.

> Any example of store implementing the NonBlockingStore transactional methods? Mostly wondering to make sure that all calls are from the same thread?

You can see some at https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan/blob/main/persistence/jdbc/src/main/java/org/infinispan/persistence/jdbc/stringbased/JdbcStringBasedStore.java#L724. The methods can and will be invoked from different metehods, thus why it stores a Map keyed by the Transaction.

> Wanted to disable the compatibility test, since not supported in prior versions. Changed group to unstable or manual and would always still get called, which doesn't seem to match documentation. What is the right way to disable it from build time run?

Not sure I understand the question. For your store you shouldn't need any compatibility test, so just don't copy that test file.

> Are there any kind of performance/stress tests for persistence store that can be executed or adapted?

We have https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-benchmarks/blob/main/cachestores/src/main/java/org/infinispan/jmhbenchmarks/InfinispanHolder.java that should work.